# KeyPairGenerator hangs UI

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

The problem is `generatorOfKeyPairs.generateKeyPair()` hangs the UI disregarding if it is executed on the main thread or the **background** thread.
For mid-range phone the time is 2-20s. For cheap devices time is up to a minute. Time measured between `Log.d(TAG, "start");` and `Log.d(TAG, "end");`
How to fix this?
PS.
Security providers other than `"AndroidKeyStore"` does not hang the UI, but I have to use this one, because it is more secure, as a private key material is never exposed.

Code used to generate `KeyPair`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler();

    @BindView(R.id.start_button)
    Button start_button;
    @BindView(R.id.time_text)
    TextView time_text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        start_button.setOnClickListener(view ->
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "hang_button click");

            start_button.setEnabled(false);
            time_text.setText("Started");

            generateKeypairAsync();
        });
    }

    private void generateKeypairAsync()
    {
        // Main thread

        mainThreadHandler.post(() ->
        {
            AsyncTask.execute(() ->
            {
                // Background thread

                KeypairGenerationResult res = generateKeypair("alias_of_key");

                mainThreadHandler.post(() ->
                {
                    // Main thread

                    start_button.setEnabled(true);
                    time_text.setText(String.format("Time: %.2f", res.generationTimeMs / 1000.0));
                });
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Method to generate KeyPair synchronously.
     */
    private static KeypairGenerationResult generateKeypair(String aliasOfKey)
    {
        Calendar dateValidFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar dateValidTo = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateValidTo.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        KeyGenParameterSpec specOfKey = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(aliasOfKey, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setKeySize(4096)
                .setKeyValidityStart(dateValidFrom.getTime())
                .setKeyValidityEnd(dateValidTo.getTime())
                .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal(String.format("CN=%s", "CertName")))
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                .build();

        try
        {
            KeyPairGenerator generatorOfKeyPairs = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
            generatorOfKeyPairs.initialize(specOfKey);

            Log.d(TAG, "start");

            long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            KeyPair keyPair = generatorOfKeyPairs.generateKeyPair();
            long timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart;

            Log.d(TAG, "end, time ms: " + timeDiff);

            return new KeypairGenerationResult(keyPair, timeDiff);
        }
        catch (GeneralSecurityException ex)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot generate wrapping keypair, exception: " + ex.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Android Studio project using this method is here: https://github.com/Mr-Goldberg/KeyPairGeneratorSpeedTest

Comment: Generating RSA keypairs can take awhile but as far as hanging the UI that's suggestive that you are either running the keygeneration in the UI thread or wait for the key generation thread to finish in a method that blocks until the thread is finished.

Comment: Is it possible to use Elliptic Curves instead of RSA? You could create a key pair for a 256 bit curve, which has both higher (classical) key **strength** as well as a very fast key pair generation algorithm.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It might be that they require exclusive access to the CPU to avoid timing attacks and other side channels. But sure, it might also be a programming error.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I am waiting, but also on background thread. Will re-check soon in clear environment to avoid any king of programming error.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have strict requirements from the client, can't use another algorithm.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Checked in the clean project in a background thread - it still hangs UI, no programming error here. Also, it hangs not just app UI, but the System UI; so you may be right about `"they require exclusive access to the CPU to avoid timing attacks and other side channels"`. But I don't have seen any mention of it in the documentation, while this is a very unpleasant user experience.

Comment: Remember, you have access to all the code and I have access to none of it. The best anybody can do here is guess. I have seen no other reports of the UI hanging during key generation using AndroidKeystore and lots of people use it to generate keys.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I've pushed Android Studio sample project into https://github.com/Mr-Goldberg/KeyPairGeneratorSpeedTest , could you check? "Start" button will start generating key. While "Does it hang?" button does nothing - just for testing UI responsiveness.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Also added the whole sample code into the question. Could you check please?

Comment: can we see the code for the `.execute` method on `AsyncTask` class?

Comment: No. `AsyncTask` is an Android component. `AsyncTasks.execute` working perfectly well for any other heavy work. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#execute(Params...)

Comment: the same problem, do you find solution?