# Android KeyPairGenerator with RSA algorithm freeze UI

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, keystore, android-keystore

I know that my question is a duplicate of an [existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63071578/keypairgenerator-hangs-ui), but that question still doesn't have an answer. At the moment I have the following code to generate a key pair.

```
keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, ANDROID_KEYSTORE)

private fun createKeyPair() {
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(
            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setKeySize(4096)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                .build()
        )
        keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
    }
```

I chose the RSA algorithm because I need asymmetric encryption (encryption with public key
and decryption using biometrics). However, the key generation **freezes ui for a few seconds**. I have a progress bar and it freezes when the key pair is generated.

I've tried putting the generation code on a background thread, but that doesn't work and still freeze. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, because I see similar logic in many apps, but I didn't notice freezes there.

Perhaps I need to use a different encryption algorithm? But the documentation does not say that there are any problems with the RSA algorithm and I don't understand how to rewrite this code and encryption code using ECC algorithm as advised in mentioned answer

here is my encryption code:

```
private const val ALGORITHM = "RSA"

private var cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)

private fun initCipherForEncrypt() {
        if (!keyStoreInstance.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
            keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
            createKeyPair()
        }

        val key: PublicKey = keyStoreInstance.getCertificate(KEY_ALIAS).publicKey
        val unrestricted: PublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance(key.algorithm).generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec(key.encoded))
        val spec = OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT)
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, unrestricted, spec)
    }

fun encrypt(token: String): ByteArray {
        initCipherForEncrypt()
        return cipher.doFinal(token.toByteArray())
    }
```

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122028783

This is an known issue, and please report it directly to google team

Comment: yes I saw it, but the problem is in the "Won't fix (Obsolete)" status, and the link they gave returns 500 code. How I can do this without RSA to avoid ui freezes?

Comment: I tracked this issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/267647326